# I have a sound project. For blind children ages 3-10 years to consult

Tags: microphone, field-recording, sound, sound-effects-recording, microphone-technique

I have a project for blind children 3-10 years old.
This project is about listening.
Because I have to provide information on various listening environment or other.
For example
As the blind child is about to cross the street.
And there came a car with a horn.
how Sound must be loud ???
Children should stop walking. For safety

So I want to use the principle of binuaral microphones.
Because the sound must be very real. In order to provide unbiased information.
If I use the 3dio mic to record the location. How realistic are they?

Is there any mic or recording principle? Can be used or modified to meet the teaching of these children.
Thank you

Ps. Sorry For My English Skill

Comment: That’s interesting. I am curious if binaural recordings would work on blind people because their hearing is much more acute than a seeing person. But in my experience recording and listening to binaural audio is that it is only convincing when the source is within a few feet (if not inches) of the microphones. I’ve never used a 3dio but have heard a bit and they seem to have the same effect. As the source is further away it becomes a basic stereo effect instead of directional, especially in the lows. But that’s my personal experience which could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Binaural would be a good choice for this project, however a better choice might be to use 1st or 2nd order ambisonics. This is very common in the VR world. Ambisonics allows a full 360 degree sound field to be recorded and rendered. When it is played back, the playback device will compensate for the position of the head, so even though the person is blind, they will still experience value in the VR experience as they will experience the full 360 degree sound field.

People use head-movement to consolidate source location and this is even more pronounced where people are blind. A head-tracking VR playback device would be very suitable in this situation.

You should consider looking at the Soundfield series of microphones and using VR post-production and mastering for replay as a B-Format Ambisonic signal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the children listening with a headphone I strongly recommend using, as already mentioned, binaural recording with a dummy head. But you could also try to experiment with different stereo microphone setups like AB (spaced omnis) or XY setup.